# Access samba3 share via terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, mount, samba

i have a raspberry pi with samba3 on it (network access for my external HDD)

And i have ubuntu14.04 on my laptop.

For one on my scripts im working with i need to access the HDD via terminal.

I tried some things ive found online, for example:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt -o username=xxx,password=yyy
mount -t cifs -o username=kagu-chan //server/horo /media/horo
```

I get the error:
    mount error: could not resolve address for server: Unknown error

Server is named horo and is accessible at 192.168.0.205 - How to access via terminal or how to mount it on media/horo?

(And - when mounted, how to auto mount at each restart of computer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount a Samba share at boot by including a line like the following in your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
   //IPAddressOfSambaServer/NameOfSambaShare /home/myusername/mountpoint cifs credentials=/root/.credentials 0 0
```

The `/root/.credentials` file (required under `root` directory because the share is mounted by root at boot) has the following form:

```
        # cat /root/.credentials
          username=MyUserName
          password=MyPassword
          domain=MyDomainIfNeeded
```

If you put this into your '/etc/fstab' file during a session, you can then mount it simply with `sudo mount -a`, which is the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks - the //IPAdress/NAME point was that was ive made wrong. Later ill try to automount, but it should work then.